# How to continuously listen for data from android client?

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

I am trying to receive data from android client to java server using tcp socket programming, but the problem is that its not listening and receiving data.I want to receive data continuously. can anyone help.

Android client:

```
package com.example.clientserver;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Button sendButton;
    private EditText messageText;
    private String messageToSend;
    private ClientSender clientSender;
    private Context context;
    private Socket socket;

    private static String SERVER_IP = "192.168.41.32";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        messageText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_button);
        context = this.getApplicationContext();
        clientSender = new ClientSender(context);
        socket = null;

        sendButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                messageToSend = messageText.getText().toString()
                        + System.getProperty("line.separator");
                new ClientSender(context).execute(messageToSend);

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
     private class ClientSender extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Socket> {
            private Socket socket;
            private String answer;
            private Context context;
            private BufferedWriter out;
            private BufferedReader in;

            public ClientSender(Context context) {
                this.context = context;
                socket = null;
                out = null;
                in = null;
            }

            @Override
            protected Socket doInBackground(String... params) {
                try {
                    if (socket == null) {
                        socket = new Socket(SERVER_IP, 4000);

                        out = new BufferedWriter(
                                new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
                        in = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                    }

                    out.write(params[0]);
                    out.flush();

                    answer = in.readLine() + System.getProperty("line.separator");

                    return socket;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return socket;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Socket socket) {
                if (socket != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, answer, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Can't connect to server!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }

        }

}
```

Server side:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javaapplication4;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author Mona
 */
public class Server extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    ServerSocket serverSocket;
    Socket socket;
    int port = 4000;

    /**
     * Creates new form Server
     */
    public Server() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(169, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGap(158, 158, 158))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(140, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGap(137, 137, 137))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        try {
            // TODO add your handling code here:
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);

                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("start Listening");
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                //InputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                String message = in.readLine();

              //  byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                //  int size = stream.read(buffer); // blockiert bis Nachricht empfangen
                // String data = new String(buffer, 0, size);
                System.out.println("strings" + message);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;

                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Server.class
                    .getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Server.class
                    .getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Server.class
                    .getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Server.class
                    .getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Server().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

How to write Server which continuously receive string data from client. I have written code but its not receiving data. I want server side which receives data whenever "send" button from android is clicked. help anybody.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22719106/java-client-server-chatting-program?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: no server program is not working for me with android